# Creating a keypad matrix that will communicate wirelessly with an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, button, wireless

I have a 30 button matrix and I would like to use a keyboard encoder to decipher what button was pressed. I would like that information (what button was pressed) to be wirelessly sent to my arduino uno nearby. What is the easiest solution? Can/how can I incorporate Arduino's Bluetooth shield to achieve this?

Comment: Which keyboard encoder? Or are you asking how to make one? Are you planning to have a second Arduino adjacent to the matrix to encode the keypresses?

Comment: Bluetooth is overkill, and unnecessarily complex for this simple task. Try looking and XBee, NRF24L01, or those cheap 433MHz transmitter/receiver pairs.

Comment: NRF24L01 is the best option. Takes the lowest amount of power if properly configured.